# Cannot edit any SharePoint forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When in designer, everytime I try to edit a dispform (or any form), I get "The server could not complete your request." In the more details section, it says "soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Cannot complete this action. Please try again. ---> Cannot complete this action. Please try again."

I've tried editing the AAM. I've used the hostname, extended name, even localhost on the server itself and I still get the error. I even went as far as building a brand new web app, and I still get this error.

Comment: can you clear all the cache files that will be under c:\users..\appdata to see if it resolves by connecting again. Also, see if there are any log entries in the event log as well as sharepoint log files.

Comment: I've tried it on a remote machine and the local server. Which machine should I clear the cache on?

Comment: on your remote machine. what about the log file analysis ? what is the version of designer you are trying and Sharepoint version ?

Comment: Could it be that you are short of memory on the server?